# ArangoDB Slow Query

Tags: arangodb

I'm new to ArangoDB, having trouble optimizing my queries and am hoping for some help.

The query I've provided below is a real example that I'm struggling with, **758.078 ms** on my dev database but on staging, with a much larger dataset, it takes **531.511 s**.

I'll also provide the size of each of the edge tables I'm traversing in dev and staging. Any help is really appreciated.

```
for doc in document
filter repo._key == "my-key"
    for v, e, p in 3 any doc edge1, edge2, edge3
    options {uniqueVertices: 'global', bfs: true}
    filter DATE_ISO8601(p.vertices[2].date) > DATE_ISO8601("2017-09-04T00:00:01Z")
        and DATE_ISO8601(p.vertices[2].date) < DATE_ISO8601("2017-09-15T23:59:59Z")
    limit 1
    return {
        commit: p.vertices[2].hash,
        date: p.vertices[2].date,
        message: p.vertices[2].message,
        author: p.vertices[1].email,
        loc: p.vertices[3].stats.additions
    }
```

**DEV**

- edge1: 2,638
- edge2: 2,560
- edge3: 386

**STAGING**

- edge1: 5,438,811
- edge2: 5,544,028
- edge3: 423,545

Answer (score 2):

The query is potentially slow because the filter condition

```
filter 
  DATE_ISO8601(p.vertices[2].date) > DATE_ISO8601("2017-09-04T00:00:01Z"
and 
  DATE_ISO8601(p.vertices[2].date) < DATE_ISO8601("2017-09-15T23:59:59Z")
```

is not applied during the traversal but only afterwards.
Potentially this is due to the function calls (to `DATE_ISO8601`) in the filter conditions. If your date values are stored as numbers, can you check whether the following filter condition speeds up the query:

```
filter 
  p.vertices[2].date > DATE_TIMESTAMP("2017-09-04T00:00:01Z"
and 
  p.vertices[2].date < DATE_TIMESTAMP("2017-09-15T23:59:59Z")
```

That modified filter condition should allow pulling the filter condition inside the traversal, so it is executed earlier.

You can verify the query execution plans using `db._explain(<query string goes here>);` in the ArangoShell or from the web interface's AQL editor.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. How would I apply my filter to the traversal? I don't know that I've seen an example of that so not sure how to restructure that piece of the query.

Comment: I think you can just replace your filter condition with the one I proposed. That will however only work if your date values are stored as numbers.
You can then check the execution plan of the query using the web interface. The execution plan should change in the sense that in the "Traversals" section at the bottom of it, the filter condition should show up. Whereas in the original query the filter condition should not be shown in the "Traversals" section.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but it will help someone. Using the DATE function will make the query much slower, so if possible remove the DATE function. For example
enter image description here[image]

You can see that the query filter command uses a Date function that is ~ 7s. If you do not use the date function, it will run faster than ~ 0.5s. These two lines will query the data of 2018-09-29.